# Composer not failing to require PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser but functions are undefined

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) package with composer but I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html()
```

when I try to call the file_get_html() function.

I successfully installed the package through composer and I can even see the package in my composer/installed.json file. Running composer update returns:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

I have of course called:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

at the top of my file and all of my other packages work fine. I know I could just require it directly instead of using composer and autoload but was wondering why this was happening.

Comment: Show code where you call it

Comment: @Eakethet where I call the function? I literally just tried `$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: Now look at the package page on github - section "Usage" and compare it to your code - wrong usage.